# need to extract part of a json like list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am working with an API and am having some issues getting it to output correctly. I am looking to extract each id and pass it to another api call. Currently api_response shows that it is a list. What is my best method for doing this. I have thought about using RE for this?

```
api_response = api_instance.graph_user_group_members_list(group_id, content_type, accept,limit=limit, skip=skip, x_org_id=x_org_id)
```

[image]

Comment: always put code as text not image.

Comment: I did not get exactly what you want - why don't you access each element of the list handling it by id as required?
Like:
  
`for element in api_response:    
    if element['to']['id']:  
        make_some_actions(element)`

Comment: you can convert JSON to Python's data and get values like from normal list/dictionary.

Comment: @furas it seems that response is already list of  python dicts (looking on the screenshot)

Comment: @VladimirKolenov yes I see it but it seems OP doesn't know it if he want to use RE.

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension

```
[each_item['to']['id'] for each_item in api_response if 'id' in each_item['to']]]
```